# Mousehover is not working in IE using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I have used the below code for mouse over in tab and select the menu in  the table. 
Mouse hover is working fine on Firefox but it is not working on Chrome and Internet Explorer. 
Before selecting the Menu, we have selected the iframe.
Please suggest alternative method to handle mouse-hover in IE WebDriver I have used the actions method for mouse-hover.

```
action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(landingpage).perform(); 
landingpage.click(); 
System.out.println(" menu tab is clicked on FF" ); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WebElement tabLinkff = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainmenu.service']/li/ul[1]/li/ul[3]/li[2‌​]/a")); 

if(tabLinkff.isEnabled()) { 
    System.out.println("work corner is identified"); 
    tabLinkff.click();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question in proper way: use `code sample` editing for your code only

Comment: Where is the code you used ?

Comment: action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(landingpage).perform();
            landingpage.click();
            System.out.println(" menu tab is clicked on FF" );
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement  tabLinkff = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainmenu.service']/li/ul[1]/li/ul[3]/li[2]/a"));
                        if(tabLinkff.isEnabled())  
    { 
         System.out.println("work corner is identified");
                         tabLinkff.click();}

Comment: Adding code from comments, formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were working with `<iframe>` before working on `mousehover`.
Did you move back to the main window by using the `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` method proceeded by the `mousehover` actions?

Comment: yes . i have  switch over the  default contents using driver.switchTo().defaultContent() comment. even though i have switchover the default content , flickering is occurring in IE. Please let me know i know use implicit wait for find out the element